# Separar strings de um ArrayList com virgula

Tags: java, string

Não tenho muito conhecimento de Java, gostaria de separar as string da minha List, com ", ".

```
List<String> nomes = Arrays.asList("Paulo", "Ana", "Zeno", "Beno");

for(int i=0; i<nomes.size(); i++) {
    System.out.format("%s%s", nomes.get(i), 
        i != nomes.size() - 1 ? ", " : " ");
}
```

Mas não achei uma boa solução, tentei também com o `foreach` do Java 8, porém não consegui.

Comment: Já tentou fazer algo como `String.join(", ", nomes)`?

Comment: Somente para exibir na tela? Se sim, basta apenas `System.out.println(nomes);` veja: https://ideone.com/f0yjBL

Comment: Era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não precisa de nenhum laço de repetição, a própria classe `String` possui um método chamado `join` que converte uma lista em *string*, utilizando outra *string* como separador.

```
List<String> nomes = Arrays.asList("Paulo", "Ana", "Zeno", "Beno");
String todosNomes = String.join(", ", nomes);
```

Se fizer `System.out.println(todosNomes)`, terá na tela: `Paulo, Ana, Zeno, Beno`.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/WYvHY7).

Comment: A String todosNomes, não devia ser um Array?

Comment: Neste caso, não, pois pelo o que entendi da pergunta você quer exibir (ou obter) uma string com todos os nomes separados por vírgula e é exatamente isso que este código faz.

Answer (score 4):

Se for apenas para exibir na tela, não precisa utilizar nenhum tipo de comando especial, basta exibir pela saida de texto padrão do java:

```
System.out.println(nomes);
```

Saida:

> [Paulo, Ana, Zeno, Beno]

Esta é a exibição padrão do ArrayList, definido pelo o seu método `toString()`, como pode ser visto abaixo(retirado do [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toString%28%29))

```
 public String toString() {
        Iterator<E> i = iterator();
        if (! i.hasNext())
            return "[]";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('[');
        for (;;) {
            E e = i.next();
            sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
            if (! i.hasNext())
                return sb.append(']').toString();
            sb.append(", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Funcionando no [ideone.com/f0yjBL](http://ideone.com/f0yjBL)