# Como faço para listar um ArrayList dentro de um JLabel

Tags: java, arraylist, jlabel

Pessoa gostaria de saber como faço para imprimir um ArrayList dentro de um JLabel, estou usando o JOptionPane mas ele mostra um elemento por vez gostaria de mostrar todos os elementos em uma unica janela.Segue o codigo da função que faz isso, como posso refazer-la ?

```
    public void pesquisar(int i){

    for(i=0 ; i < pessoas.size() ; i++){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Pessoa.toString());
      }



  }
```

Comment: Veja essa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/202836/28595

Comment: Esta também resolve seu problema: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165733/28595

Comment: Esse seu código tem sérios problemas. Primeiro, o parâmetro `i` não é usado para nada, vez que o `for` sobreescreve o valor dessa variável. Segundo, você itera os índices da lista `pessoas`, mas dentro do for, não usa nem o índice e nem a lista para nada. Terceiro que `Pessoa.toString()` ou vai ser sempre a mesma pessoa se `Pessoa` for uma variável de instância (em desacordo com o padrão de nomenclatura de variáveis) ou então é um método estático (o que provavelmente é uma má prática de programação). Quarto que nesse código você nem mesmo tenta usar um `JLabel`.